# Tangents parallel to one another and finding the perpendicular of a vector function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

We have
$$x(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1+t \\
  t^2-t \\
  1-t^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Part 1**

Are there $2$ points $x(t_1)$, $x(t_2)$, such that the function’s tangent vectors
at these points are parallel to each other? Find such points, or show that none
exist.

$$x'(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  2t-1 \\
  -2t\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

> I tried to search online but how can I prove that they are parallel to each other if I can't even find the points? I got stumped at $2t^2-2t+1=0$
>
> Basically I get a negative in a square root. And that would lead to no solution for t. My answer is wrong... or is the answer scheme wrong?

**Part 2**

Given the point $x(2)$, is there a second point such that the tangent
vectors are perpendicular to each other? Find such a point or show that it
doesn’t exist.

> How can I find the second point? And to prove that they are perpendicular do I have to differentiate twice?
>
> I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: How did you end up with that quadratic equation?

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that two vectors are parallel if $v_1=\lambda v_2$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: @amd Idk the word for it in english. I first found the magnitude(?) from the function. Then I Just simplified it.

Comment: @memerson I did not know you could do that! I will give it a go.

Comment: @memerson but where would I get   λ from?

Comment: @memerson Since we’re in $\mathbb R^3$ we can avoid introducing an extraneous variable by instead using $v_1\times v_2=0$ as the condition for parallelism, which produces two independent equations.

Comment: What does the magnitude of anything have to do with two vectors being parallel?

Comment: @amd, very true. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't consider it